# How to make org-mode agenda clocking consider all instead of current year only?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I noticed that my clocked time only consists of the clocked time in 2018 and the time in 2017 is not considered. Is there a place where I can configure that?

Comment: In order to widen the appeal of your question, you might consider adding some detail about what exactly you are doing (keystrokes, functions called, a small example of a file that produces the problem etc.) Clocking experts are a small subset of org-mode experts who in turn are a small subset of emacs experts who are a small subset of SO experts, so making it easier to set up a test rig for somebody who is not a clock expert might produce a better answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

`(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist '((:block "untilnow")))`

You can configure the org-agenda clock report using any of the parameters for a generic clocking table described [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html)